# How to differentiate Arrow keys(Rigth and Left) with Percentage and Single-Quote as it has same ASCII codes

Tags: javascript, symbols, arrow-keys

I need to allow only Alphabets or Numbers or AlphaNumeric for some input texts. So i had used normal validation by checking its ASCII codes(by return false/true). 
But it allows japanese characters. So i used below code on onkeyUp.

```
function validateElementOnkeyupWthEve(element,types,event)
{
    if(event.which == 37 || event.which == 39)
        return;
     var val = element.value;     
     var i=0;
     var ascode = 0;
     var chr = '';
     var res = '';
     for(i=0;i<val.length;i++)
     {
         ascode = val.charCodeAt(i);  
         chr = val.charAt(i);                 
         if(types=="numberonly")
         {
             if(ascode >= 48 && ascode <= 57)
             {
                 res += chr;
             }
         }
         else if(types=="filterAlphaNumeric")
         {
             if( (ascode >= 65 && ascode <= 90 ) || (ascode >= 97 && ascode <= 122 ) || (ascode >= 48 && ascode <= 57) || ascode == 32)
             {
                 res += chr.toUpperCase();
             }
         }
     }
      element.value = res;
}
```

In this code, without first two lines,

```
if(event.which == 37 || event.which == 39)
        return;
```

left arrow and right arrow not works(could not traverse). so i add it. 
Now % and ' symbols are allowing as ASCII code of both 
**left arrow and percentage is 37 
and  Rigth arrow and single-quote is 39.**

So its allowing **%** and **'** symbol. How to resolve it.

Comment: How do you type % and ' on a Japanese keyboard? because in american keyboard, you typically use Shift + 5 which is a combination of 16 & 53 ASCII codes.

Comment: ＠Shadi Shaaban, i used above code to restrict other language characters and sybmols. It will just check and remove all other chars from loop(by iterating the entered chars). Here user can not navigate the words using left and right arrow button. Because, for every onkeyup, it rechecks in loop and sets again and cursor moves to end. So, i check ascii codes for left and right arrow keys and returned when it occurs. My problem is left arrow and % has same ascii code 37, rigth arrow and ' has same ascii code 39. so these two symbols allowed.

Comment: On which keyboard layout does % result in 37 ASCII code?

Comment: In English(United States) only. In my aplication both English and Japanese are used. For a particular screen i need to restrict japanese chars and special characters

Comment: I have tested your code above and *%* ASCII code is *53* while the SHIFT key is pressed, so I think you need to double check how could % result in 37 ASCII code in your application.